# How to add IntelliJ Run Configuration quick create?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

When using IntelliJ 15, I notice that classes which has a main will have a little icon on the left legend (see image, they are the blue window icons on line starting with "object ICE" and "def main"). When I click on one of these icons, IntelliJ suggests that I create a Run Configuration for this class.

What is this feature called? Is it Run Configuration Provider?

I have already had a plugin that can create smart Run Configuration when I choose from the menu Run -> Run... . What interface / feature do I need to implement so my plugin can provide this "quick create" feature?

[image: IntelliJ Run Configuration helper]

Answer (score 2):

You have to register an instance of `RunLineMarkerContributor` using the extension point `runLineMarkerContributor`.

See [ApplicationRunLineMarkerProvider.java](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/7bf754f94ba19aa1884b3b9be7dc72ddf6f2e102/java/execution/impl/src/com/intellij/execution/application/ApplicationRunLineMarkerProvider.java) for an example. Note that this was added in IntelliJ 15, you won't be able to build your plugin with an SDK < 15, although older versions will still be able to run your plugin because they will simply ignore this extension point.